# How is object code copied into executable when linking against static library?

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries

I am reading the O'Reilly book [21st Century C](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025108.do), in which the author states that when linking against a static library:

> The compiler [is effectively] copying the relevant contents of the library into the final executable.

I have tried to test this by creating my own static library consisting of this module:

```
static char szStr[64];

char* single_func() {
    strcpy(szStr, "Hello string!\r\n");
    return szStr;
}

void func0() {
    strcpy(szStr, "Hello");
}

char* func1() {
    strcat(szStr, " string!\r\n");
    return szStr;
}
```

For testing, I created two C files where one is calling `single_func()` and the other calls `func0()` and `func1()`.

The resulting executables are 751290B in both cases. If I call `strcpy` and `strcat` directly from the modules both executables end up being 7215B.

Does this not conflict with the above statement, or am I missing some detail about linking?

A related question is that the static library is 1600B, so where does this increase in size come from?

---

Additional:

Both main files consist of nothing more than calling the functions and printing the results, like this:

main0:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sharedlib.h"
int main() {
    char* szStr = single_func();
    printf("%s", szStr);
    return 0;
}
```

main1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sharedlib.h"
int main() {
    char* szStr;
    func0();
    szStr = func1();
    printf("%s", szStr);
    return 0;
}
```

Files were compiled like this:

```
gcc -static main0.c -L. -lsharedlib -o main0
```

Platform is linux and the compiler is gcc v4.6.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With static libraries, the unit of copying is the object file in the library.  Since both your programs call a function from the object file, both programs end up with all of the object file in the executable, hence the same size result (give or take the size of the calling `main()` program).

The extra information in the executable could come from several places.  Some of it will be control and debug information.  Some of it might be from the C library if you linked that statically too.  We'd probably need to see the main program and the link lines, and know the platform to come up with other reasons for the inflation.

Comment: I have updated my question with the extra information you asked for but I think I can start to see where this is going. 1: When using a single function from a library's object file the entire object file is rolled into the executable. 2: by using the -static option _all_ libraries are rolled into the final executable, producing the larger file size. Am I correct in this?

Comment: Yes; you're right in both particulars.  If you look at Plauger's book 'The Standard C Library' (for the C89 standard), you'd see that most source files have one externally visible function so that you don't drag what you don't use into the executable.  You could probably reduce the size of your executable dramatically by adding `-shared` to the command line after `-lsharedlib`.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that the C library is being (seems to be being) linked statically.  At one time (a decade ago, perhaps) I thought that the C library was not supplied as a static library (so it had to be shared).  I may be misremembering, or it may have been on a Unix variant rather than Linux.  You could check what's being loaded as a shared library with `ldd main0`.  It will list the shared objects used.

Comment: When compiling using the static option `ldd main0` gives "not a dynamic executable" so the c library is appearently statically linked with it. I must admit I had not checked this as I believed, like you said, that it did not come in a static version. Using the -shared options drops file size to about a 10th of the original and `ldd main0` lists libc.so.6 as a linked library. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that get it to work with a dynamically linked libc you need -shared-libgcc instead of -shared. Only using -shared result in a segmentation fault.